# Changing SQLException message? Java

Tags: java, exception, message

When trying to insert some duplicate data into a JTextField, that message appears:

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

How could I change it to something more intuitive like "Code already registered in the system"?

Comment: How exactly are you currently inserting the data?

Comment: The problem is not in the insert. I want only to change that message to something the user could understand.

Comment: Why that was downvoted? Probably by someone who also didn't understand my question. Hah

Comment: I know the problem is not with the insert. It's just that your question isn't clear at all, with respect to what you're trying to do. That's why it was downvoted... and it wasn't downvoted by me. You may wish to elaborate more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: What you have to do is not changing the exception message but wrap the method and update the JTextField inside the catch block, or call a method that does the same inside the catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if (the user inserts duplicate data into a JTextField) {
     throw new SQLException("Code already registered in the system.");
}
```

That will allow you to change the message.
Hope that helps a bit!

Comment: And what would be a "the user inserts duplicate data into a JTextField" condition in Java?

Comment: A tip: Use a boolean variable called checkDuplicate. If the user inserts duplicate data into a JTextField, set checkDuplicate to false. If checkDuplicate is false, then throw the exception.

Comment: No problem. :) Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Before insert, using a select statement check whether the record is already in the data base. If already exist provide your user notification else insert the data.